# VBA Excel Macro Delete Sheets With String

Tags: vba, excel

I have used a bit of VBA code to search through all sheet names in a workbook for a certain string, lets call it **"Text"**. When it finds a sheet with that string it should delete that sheet. But lets say there are four sheets with **"Text"** in the name (named **text 1**, **text 2**, **text 3** and **text 4**), instead of deleting all four, it deletes **Text 1** and **Text 3**. It leaves the 2nd and 4th as non-deleted. Then if I call the macro again it deletes **Text 2** but leaves **Text 4**. Finally if I click it again it deletes Text 4. 
I cannot work out why as it looks like it should work.

```
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
    n = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    i = 1
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do
        On Error Resume Next
        If InStr(1, Sheets(i).Name, "Text") Then Sheets(i).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until i = n
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to loop backwards to avoid skipping sheets:

```
Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
n = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = n to 1 step -1
    On Error Resume Next
    If InStr(1, Sheets(i).Name, "Text") Then Sheets(i).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Otherwise, if the code deletes sheet 1, sheet 2 becomes sheet 1, but i is incremented to 2 and so the original sheet 2 is never processed.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a VBA pro, but this might work as well if you want to give it a shot ;)

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each WS In Worksheets
' Specify the "TEXT" you are looking for in the sheet name in uppercase!
    If InStr(UCase(WS.Name), "TEXT") Then WS.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
Next WS
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: This does work so thank you but i ticked Rory's because it made more sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

You could also decrease n and not increase i as a Sheet is deleted:

```
Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
n = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
i = 1
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Do
    On Error Resume Next
    If InStr(1, Sheets(i).Name, "Text") Then 
        Sheets(i).Delete
        n = n-1
    Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop Until i = n
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Again, for others reference this does work but Rory's version makes more sense to me because of the way it is written.